# Upload File from My_Pc to Remote Linux Server Not ftp Vb.Net

Tags: linux, vb.net, file-upload, remote-server

I want to upload my selected file from My Computer to remote Linux server.(for example Selected file c:\send\manual.pdf - upload address: //MyServerIpAddress/uploads/). I use Vb.Net 2010 Windows form application, not aspx. I will make exe when the project finished. The users will run the exe on their computers and they select file then they click send button and the file will upload to remote server.
I'm not good in English. I hope I could tell what I want to do.
Thanks.

Comment: You need to specify much more details: what protocol do you want to use? Is there a server for that protocol on the remote site? Do you need any for of authentication? Any code required on the remote site? and and and...

Comment: Hi arkascha.Protocol? like ftpwebrequest or filewebrequest or httpwebrequest? The Remote Site doesn't required any code.The remote site is Ubuntu Server. I need authentication.

Comment: I have no idea what "ftpwebrequest" or "filewebrequest" are, but they are certainly not protocols, maybe they are implementations or client classes, I have no idea about Vb.net. Protocols would be `ftp` or `http` and those certainly _do_ required code on the remote site: the corresponding server actually able to deliver ("speak") that protocol.

Comment: So the first thing to decide is: which protocol. If in doubt go for `http`. Should suite the task you describe, brings little problems with firewalls and setting up an http server on the remote side is pretty easy. But you need code inside that http server to accept files, without it the server won't know what to do with them. Wither you have to implement something yourself, or you use something out-of-the-box (I would recommend owncloud.org).

Comment: Thanks arkascha. I want to use http protocols. I dare say, if I use http protocol I must to need code both of them(Client:Send,Remote Server:Read(Listen)). Is that true?

Comment: Well nearly, yes. You indeed need code on both sides. The client code sends (makes an http POST request) and the server listens. But the listening part is already there: it's done by the http server on the remote site. What is missing there is code _handling_ the uplaoded file. For example moving it to its desired location. Making security and plausibility checks. Giving feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You should connect to remote linux machine using SSH protocol and transfer files using SFTP
please refer following links for same

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b99ca652-7144-42bc-a393-d4cc08838d41/how-to-transfer-sftp-files-in-vb-net-2010?forum=vblanguage

http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/transfer-sftp-files-vb-net-2010-49096.aspx